# How to include variables inside queries using php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$query = 'select stopname from greenline';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="try.php" method="get">
      <?php
echo "<select name='myselect'>";

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
    echo '<option value=" ' . $row1[0] . ' " name="row" >' . $row1[0] . '</option>';
endwhile;
echo "</select>";
?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $variable = $_GET['myselect'];
    $query1 = 'select placeno from greenline where stopname = " ' . $variable . '"';
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    echo "success";
    $var = $row2['placeno'];
    echo " this is $var";
} ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have done as above in sublime.. it is not extract the variable value in our query.could you please give a solution.. $var is not being displayed

Comment: You have a space after `"` in the query. So it won't match what's in the database.

Comment: i did that!! it still doesnt help!

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo $query1`?

Comment: BTW, `die(myql_error())` should be `die(mysqli_error($connect))`

Comment: if i echo $query1.. the entire query along with the substituted variable is being displayed.. which basically means that the value of the variable is being extracted and being substituted in the query but the query is still not giving a valid output

Comment: What happens if you then execute the query by hand?

Comment: $query1='select placeno from greenline where stopname="'.$variable.'"';         This command is implicitly concatenating a space before and after my variable.. how do i get rid of that?

Comment: See my updated answer. You're adding spaces in the HTML. Why aren't you looking for these carefully, instead of assuming that the software is doing something implicitly?

Comment: Computers are very obedient, they do exactly what you tell them to do, no more, no less.

Comment: tysm for all the help! extra space removed! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have `;` right after `while`. This makes your loop a no-op, basically.

Also remove `:` at the same place.

Comment: I think you don't understand that PHP allows two styles of block statements. You can either wrap the body with `{}`, or you can start the body with `:` and end with `endXXX`. He's using the second form.

Comment: @Barmar whoa, didn't know about that, thanks. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to delete an answer from the Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in the query:

```
$query1='select placeno from greenline where stopname = " '.$variable.'"';
                                                         ^
```

Remove that space and it will work.

But it would be better if you used a prepared statement instad of substituting variables.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, 'select placeno from greenline where stopname = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $variable);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $placeno);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
echo "this is $placeno";
```

You're also adding extra spaces in the html:

```
echo '<option value=" ' . $row1[0] . ' " name="row" >' . $row1[0] . '</option>';
                     ^                ^
```

Get rid of these spaces as well.